# Why sometimes Java process builder only get 1 line of the process output?

Tags: java, docker, processbuilder

When you execute "docker history [id] -q" in terminal, you will get a list of id strings.

Now I wanna get the string list through java program. However, sometimes I can only get the first line of the output. (this happens randomly, when I repeatedly run the same command).

The code is showed below, anyone got ideas about it? Thanks you so much!

```
 String[] cmdParaArray = {"docker", "history", ID, "-q"};
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 CmdExecutor.execute(cmdParaArray, baos);
 String imageInfoJsonString = baos.toString();


 public static List<String> execute(String[] cmdParaArray, OutputStream os) {
  try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdParaArray)
                .redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process proc = pb.start();

        InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader reader
                = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (os != null) {
                os.write((line + "\n").getBytes());
                os.flush();
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: That's unrelated but why do you first convert the bytes to text and read them line by line just to convert them back to bytes for storage in the `OutputStream`?

Comment: @SubOptimal Whether the process finishes before you read all lines is irrelevant. They are still present in the I/O system and available to be read. There is nothing in your link that states the contrary.